# How to define a slick joinCondition

Tags: scala, slick

In the scaladays 2013 talk http://www.parleys.com/play/51c2e20de4b0d38b54f46243/chapter55/agenda it talks about "joinCondition"

For example:

```
implicit def autojoin1 = joinCondition[Sites,Devices](_.id === _.siteId)
implicit def autojoin2 = joinCondition[Devices,Computers](_.computerId === _.id)
sites.autoJoin(devices).further(computers)
  : Query[_,(Site,Computer)]
sites.autoJoin(devices).autoJoinVia(computers)(_._2)
 : Query[_,((Site,Device),Computer)]
```

I'm very new to scala, and can't figure out what joinCondition is, I can't find any method or anything named that in slick(1.0.0) and can't get it to work, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the talk (but not listed in the slides) the complete autoJoin feature is not currently offered by Slick, but part of a demo Play project we prepared. The code is here https://github.com/cvogt/play-slick/blob/scaladays2013/samples/computer-database/app/util/autojoin.scala (and in the other files in https://github.com/cvogt/play-slick/blob/scaladays2013/samples/computer-database/app/)

Comment: Thank you, i had tried to find the sample repo but it was a dead link and didn't find it through the github search

Comment: Where was the dead link?

Comment: last slide of the video

Comment: I found the autojoin sample interesting, but hard to use on a production project. It means that we have to wait for a better support in Slick 2.x

Comment: What was hard about it in production? The types?

Answer (score 1):

Check also this blog article, that presents a solution for Slick 2.0 http://tikokelottlegyenviz.blogspot.fr/2013/08/scala-slick-left-join.html